# Recover ipython nbagg figure

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am using ipython with nbagg matplotlib backend,

`%matplotlib nbagg
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

and having trouble controlling the inline figures display. When I execute a cell with `plt.plot()` an interactive nbagg inline figure with editing controls appears.

`a=np.linspace(0,1)
plt.plot(a, np.sinc(a))`

[image: nbagg inline figure]

However, when I make a change to the cell and run it to produce another plot, the inline figure disappears.

`a=np.linspace(0,1)+2
plt.plot(a, np.sinc(a))
Out[38]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1341e080>]`

How can I make it reappear again with both plots?

Nothing happens when I call `plt.show()` or `plt.gca()`. When I do `plt.gcf()`, the plot reappears with both curves, but without nbagg controls, so it is not interactive anymore. The only way I can get back to interactive plotting is creating a new figure `plt.figure()`, or closing the current one `plt.close(); plt.gcf()`, none of which gets me to my old curves. I can plot the second and further curves from other cells, but that seems a strange and inconvenient limitation.

I am on the latest ipython 4.0 and matplotlib, but had the same problem on 3.2.1.